# Borel algebra mod meagre sets vs. Borel algebra mod sets of measure zero

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, boolean-algebra, descriptive-set-theory

Are there any circumstances in which the Borel algebra modulo meagre sets is isomorphic to the Borel algebra modulo sets of measure zero?

Comment: Isomorphic in what sense?

Comment: They are in the same for spaces with a so-called "category measure" (Oxtoby introduced this, IIRC). Those are pretty strange spaces..

Comment: Thanks Henno. Also, I am almost sure that I read somewhere (probably Fund. Math., butI can't remember precisely) that there exists a transformation which links both. Are you aware of such a transformation?

Comment: Sure. Assume that the real numbers are a countable union of countable sets. Then all sets of reals are Borel and both ideals are everything, and therefore the quotients are isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

[Measure and Category by Oxtoby](http://math.rice.edu/~michael/teaching/426_Spr14/Banach_Mazur.pdf), in chapter 22,considers this problem.
First he sketches how you cannot find such isomorphisms for many metric spaces, and then defines a Category measure as topological spaces  with a measure such that the sets of measure $0$ and those of first category (meagre sets) are the same.

He then shows that one can sometimes define a topology on a measurable space to make it such a measure space. An important example  is the density topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I also know of Kunen's compact $L$-space under CH (in Fund. Math.) that obeys this.