# Cantor set and category measure space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, boolean-algebra

This question is related to my previous post

[Borel algebra mod meagre sets vs. Borel algebra mod sets of measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353768/borel-algebra-mod-meagre-sets-vs-borel-algebra-mod-sets-of-measure-zero)

Can the Borel algebra mod meagre set be isomorphic to the Borel algebra mod sets of measure zero if the underlying space is the Cantor set? In other words, is (or can) the Cantor set (be) a category measure space?

Comment: In the same topology no. In a different topology/measure: just take the reals in the in the density topology and use a bijection to transport measure and topology to $C$. Boring, but works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please precise in what sense you think it is boring?

Comment: It only uses the cardinality of $C$.